# Is anyone familiar with Bamboo sharepoint products?

Tags: sharepoint, bamboo, suite

We are looking at 3rd party application solution providers for SharePoint, and are interested in the Bamboo products (bamboosolutions.com).
Has anyone had any experience with these products?  Are they stable?  Have they caused you issues?  Are they worth the money?
Specifically we are looking at the PDF converter, but would like to expand into their administration suites as well in the future.
What are your thoughts on Bamboo software products?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to visit http://sharepointreviews.com/ for consumer reviews of SharePoint products.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo have been around for quite a while and they have a wide range of products so I assume they are OK. Have heard some people complain about their support though.

Shameless plug, but if you are looking at PDF Conversion for SharePoint then have a look at [this product](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) as well. It is more affordable and I understand more flexible as well.

Comment: I'll second the complaint about support. We're currently evaluating their List Search web part, and overall the product seems good. But getting just a few questions answered about it has proven difficult -- way too difficult considering we're a potential customer.